# Speeding up website - marking scripts/images as optional?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, web

On my website I have ads from a network that does not load particularly fast. Some browsers won't draw the page unless the ads load, making the website appear slower than it actually is - is there any way to prevent this? As in mark the script as non-essential or do some javascript trick to only draw it once it's loaded? I tried googling a solution, but to no avail.

Also, some ads are added to the site as iframe, some as JS script (much like adsense)

Answer (score 3):

If loading the ads is optional, what you could do is wait to load them and then use ajax to load/add them later with jquery.

Comment: This is wrong.  That block of code has nothing to do with the page being done loading and rendering... it's for when the DOM is loaded and available.  See also:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is defer the loading of your ads, and anything else non-essential, until after the page has finished loading.

Attach code to load these to `window.onload`.  That event fires when everything on the page is done loading.  You can even defer loading the whole script by adding it to the DOM later.  I use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for this, but there are other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Load the ad after the DOM has been loaded. You would have your page load normally, then bind a function (JavaScript) which injects the ad(s).

There is also the defer attribute on  tags, but it isn't fully cross-browser supported.

[JavaScript: Defer Execution](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/)

Comment: You don't want to just wait for the DOM... that happens very quickly.  You want to wait for other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put your script tags at the bottom of the page, before the closing body tag. http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html
Or you could try to load them asynchronously.

In HTML5 (not as much browser support)

```
<script async src="http://your.com/script.js"></script>
```

Another way (works with more browsers)

```
<script>
   var resource = document.createElement('script'); 
   resource.src = "//your.com/script.js";
   var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
</script>
```

http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/